# What is the probability (10-faces 3D shape rolled)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In the 10-faces 3D shape:in 4 faces is written number 1, in 3 faces is written number 2, in 3 faces is written number 3. This shape is rolled 8 times. What is the probability that the face with number 3 drops 3 times, with the number 2 drops 2 times and with the number 1 drops 3 times.
I was thinking to do (3/10)^3 * (3/10)^2 * (4/10)^3 but i know that we have to put some combinations here and i’m sucked here. Please solve if you can telling all ur steps. Thank you!

Comment: You are on the right track (+1), except for the required multinomial coefficient to count the number of arrangements of the desired outcomes. See my Answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

Analytically, this is a [multinomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) probability. You want three `1`s, two `2`a and three `3`s in 8 rolls, where the probabilities of `1`a, `2`s, and `3`a are
$.4, .3, .3,$ respectively. That is,

$${8 \choose {3,2,3}}(.4)^3(.3)^2(.3)^3 =  0.0870912,$$
where the multinomial coefficient $\frac{8!}{3!\cdot 2!\cdot 4!} = 560.$

This probability can be simulated by imagining a die with ten faces
labeled $100,100,100,100,10,10,10,1,1,1$ instead of $1,1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3,3,$
so that the desired total on the eight rolls will be `323`. In ten million
rolls of such a die we got this total  $870,670$
times for a simulated probability of $0.087067,$ which agrees with the
analytic result to the anticipated three or four-place accuracy.

```
die = c(100,100,100,100,10,10,10,1,1,1)
set.seed(2020)
tot= replicate(10^7, sum(sample(die,8,rep=T)))
mean(tot==323)
[1] 0.087067
```